# Trying to draw circle on Laser pointer, OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

So i have taken the code from Github of @bradmontgomer and trying to modify it. The code first converts the frame into HSV color space, split the video frame into color channels and then Performs an AND on HSV components to identify the laser. I am having trouble in finding the contours of the detected laser point. heres my code;

```
    def threshold_image(self, channel):
    if channel == "hue":
        minimum = self.hue_min
        maximum = self.hue_max
    elif channel == "saturation":
        minimum = self.sat_min
        maximum = self.sat_max
    elif channel == "value":
        minimum = self.val_min
        maximum = self.val_max

    (t, tmp) = cv2.threshold(
        self.channels[channel], # src
        maximum, # threshold value
        0, # we dont care because of the selected type
        cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV #t type
    )

    (t, self.channels[channel]) = cv2.threshold(
        tmp, # src
        minimum, # threshold value
        255, # maxvalue
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY # type
    )

    if channel == 'hue':
        # only works for filtering red color because the range for the hue is split
        self.channels['hue'] = cv2.bitwise_not(self.channels['hue'])


def detect(self, frame):
    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)

    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    # split the video frame into color channels
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_img)
    self.channels['hue'] = h
    self.channels['saturation'] = s
    self.channels['value'] = v

    # Threshold ranges of HSV components; storing the results in place
    self.threshold_image("hue")
    self.threshold_image("saturation")
    self.threshold_image("value")

    # Perform an AND on HSV components to identify the laser!
    self.channels['laser'] = cv2.bitwise_and(
        self.channels['hue'],
        self.channels['value']
    )
    self.channels['laser'] = cv2.bitwise_and(
        self.channels['saturation'],
        self.channels['laser']
    )

    # Merge the HSV components back together.
    hsv_image = cv2.merge([
        self.channels['hue'],
        self.channels['saturation'],
        self.channels['value'],
    ])

    thresh = cv2.threshold(self.channels['laser'], 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

        #find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        #(x, y) center of the ball
    #cnts = cv2.findContours(self.channels['laser'].copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    #cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    center = None          

        # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
            # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
            # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
            # centroid
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

            # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
            if radius > 10:
                # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
                # then update the list of tracked points
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                    (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)            
    cv2.imshow('LaserPointer', self.channels['laser'])
    ################################################
    return hsv_image
```

I am getting the cnts greater then 0 in line "if len(cnts) > 0:", but can't see a circle drawn in the laser pointer. [image: this is the still frame of video, pointing the laser spot.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another function (display()) that was displaying laser frame (self.channel['laser']),

```
    def display(self, img, frame):
      """Display the combined image and (optionally) all other image channels
      NOTE: default color space in OpenCV is BGR.
      """
      cv2.imshow('RGB_VideoFrame', frame)
      cv2.imshow('LaserPointer', self.channels['laser'])
```

I commented out these cv2.iamshow lines from this function and then I was able to see circle around the laser pointer. This is because now frame from cv2.iamshow line inside function "detect(self, frame):" was executed. I then applied further codings on the pointer to detect its location. [image]